# Complex multiplication and integration with CUDA

Tags: performance, c, numerical-methods, cuda, complex-numbers

I want to perform multiplication on two vectors and integrate it in a vector called `acc_y`. The `acc_y` variable will update over every iteration and averaged out.
I have modified [vector addition code](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/) for it.

kernel for the multiply and integration:

```
__global__ void cvctmac (int M,float *yre,float *yim,float *x1re,float *x1im,float *x2re,float *x2im,double *acc_yre,double *acc_yim) {
    int index  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    // Multiplication
    for (int i = index; i < M; i += stride) {
        acc_yre[i] += x1re[i] * x2re[i] - x1im[i] * x2im[i];
        acc_yim[i] += x1re[i] * x2im[i] + x1im[i] * x2re[i];
    }
}
__global__ void cavg(int M,double iter,double *xre,double *xim){
    // Averaging
    int index  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    // Grid-stride approch
    for (int i = index; i < M; i += stride) {
        xre[i] /= iter;
        xim[i] /= iter;
    }
}
```

As the code is performing complex arithmetic, I am doing 4 operations per thread(2 for multiplication and 2 for integration). what will be the way to optimize the kernel cvctmac?

Will shared memory help here?

I have used [cuComplex.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473826/cuda-how-to-work-with-complex-numbers) also but getting the same performance.

host code:

```
for (j = 0; j < iter; j++) {

    // Generate data in host
    for (i = j * M, c = 0; i < M * (j + 1); i++, c++) {
        x1re[c] = (float)i;
        x1im[c] = 0.0;
        x2re[c] = 1.0;
        x2im[c] = 0.0;
    }

    // Copy host to device
    cudaMemcpy(dx1re, x1re, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dx1im, x1im, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dx2re, x2re, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dx2im, x2im, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //mac
    cvctmac<<<numBlock, numThread>>>(
        M,
        dyre, dyim,
        dx1re, dx1im,
        dx2re, dx2im,
        dacc_yre, dacc_yim
    );
}
// Avg
cavg<<<numBlock, numThread>>>(
    M, (double) iter,
    dacc_yre, dacc_yim
);
```

Please suggest the way to optimize the code.  I'm targeting CUDA with compute capability 6.1.